# Sort in list comprehension

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension

I have some data that looks like this

```
my_list = ['10 apples', '4 dogs', '9 cats']
```

I need to do some string modification to the the items in the list and then create two new lists.

```
headers = [words.replace(' ', '_') for words in my_list]
numbers= [nums.split()[0] for nums in my_list]
```

Is there a way to sort these inside of the list comprehension?  Right now i'm doing this, which isn't a big deal, but I thought I'd take this opportunity to learn if possible.

```
# Create lists
headers = [my_list.replace(' ', '_') for words in my_list]
numbers= [my_list.split()[0] for nums in my_list]

# Sort Lists
headers.sort(reverse = True)
numbers.sort(reverse = True)
```

I'm doing this in a pyspark environment, if that makes a difference.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Have you checked if the sorting of the numbers producing the output you want? Currently `numbers` is a list of *strings*, so they're being sorted lexicographically, not as numbers.

Comment: That code doesn't even work at all.

Comment: Right, the list comprehensions aren't using the local variable. They should be `[words.replace(' ', '_') for words in my_list]` and `[nums.split()[0] for nums in my_list]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method to sort inside a list comprehension *(There actually kind of is one. See Edit at the bottom)*. But using `sorted()` you can still do it in one line each.

```
headers = sorted([words.replace(' ', '_') for words in my_list], reverse=True)
numbers = sorted([nums.split()[0] for nums in my_list], reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
['9_cats', '4_dogs', '10_apples']
['9', '4', '10']
```

With this code `numbers` will be a list of strings so they will be sorted lexicographically, not as numbers.
To fix this just use `int()` in the comprehension and convert from string to integer. Or convert it while sorting so you will keep a list of strings.

```
# option 1
numbers = sorted([int(nums.split()[0]) for nums in my_list], reverse=True)
# option 2
numbers = sorted([nums.split()[0] for nums in my_list], reverse=True, key=lambda x: int(x))
```

Output:

```
Option 1
[10, 9, 4]
Option 2
['10', '9', '4']
```

I don't know how you want the headers list to be sorted. But if you want it be sorted by the words after `_` ('apples', 'dogs', 'cats')
you can do the following

```
headers = sorted([words.replace(' ', '_') for words in my_list], reverse=True, key=lambda x: x.split('_')[1])
```

Output:

```
['4_dogs', '9_cats', '10_apples']
```

## Edit

---

Quoting User [xavi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19626334/xavi)

> Adding to the last solution: If using sorted with that lambda, there isn't really any reason to keep it outside the list comprehension, which accomplishes the stated goal of sorting "inside the comprehension"

```
headers = [words.replace(' ', '_') for words in sorted(my_list, reverse=True, key=lambda x:x.split()[1])]
```

The same applies to `numbers`

```
numbers = [nums.split()[0] for nums in sorted(my_list, reverse=True, key=lambda x:int(x.split()[0]))]
```

Comment: Adding to the last solution: If using sorted with that lambda, there isn't really any reason to keep it outside the list comprehension, which accomplishes the stated goal of sorting "inside the comprehension": `[words.replace(' ', '_') for words in sorted(my_list, reverse=True, key=lambda x:x.split()[1])]`

Comment: @Xavi Thank you. I realised the same applies to `numbers`. I edited my Answer

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to sort these inside of the list comprehension?

A list comprehension is just a linear scan over list elements. Since it's impossible to do a comparison sort in linear time, a list comprehension cannot be used for sorting inputs.

If your question is about writing more compact code though you could call `sorted()` on the result of a list comprehension expression.

```py
my_list = ['10 apples', '4 dogs', '9 cats']

headers = sorted(
  [word.replace(' ', '_') for word in my_list], 
  key = lambda word: int(word.split('_')[0]), 
  reverse = True)
numbers = sorted([int(word.split()[0]) for word in my_list], reverse = True)

print(headers)
print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
['10_apples', '9_cats', '4_dogs']
[10, 9, 4]
```

Comment: You *can* do more than "just a linear scan" in a list comp. Could even call `.sort()` on the list after each new element. Just wouldn't be any good.

Comment: Agreed. In each of the expressions inside the list comprehension you can, of course, do anything. However, a list comprehension itself is just a linear scan, so you cannot sort **by means** of list comprehension. The question was asked a little bit ambiguously so I decided to emphasize this aspect of Python.